# setDataAsync with Office.CoercionType.Table

Tags: office365

My first day hacking with Napa and I'm struggling...

I'm struggling to understand the binding process for TableData. I've worked out a simple example with the Matrix type and can read data from an existing table:

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("Sheet1!Table1", Office.BindingType.Table, { id: "bindingTable" }, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        asyncResult.value.getDataAsync(function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                console.log(asyncResult.value);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

but I am unable to write data to a table:

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("Sheet1!Table1", Office.BindingType.Table, { id: "bindingTable" }, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        var myTable = new Office.TableData;
        myTable.headers = [["ID"],["Name"]];
        myTable.rows = [[1,"Fred"],[2,"Jane"]];
        asyncResult.value.setDataAsync(myTable, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Table }, function (asyncResult) {
            console.log(asyncResult.status);
        });
    }
});
```

Specifically, the error thrown is "Data Write Error", "The supplied data object type is not supported".

What am I doing wrong?

Also, can I programmatically generate tables on a sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I think I may have stumbled upon the answer.... the binding returned from a Office.BindingType.Table is an abstract class BindingTable that has additional methods including addRowsAsync.

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("Sheet1!Table1", Office.BindingType.Table, { id: "bindingTable" }, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        asyncResult.value.addRowsAsync([[3, "Henry"]], null, function (asyncResult) {
        console.log(asyncResult.status);
    });
}
```

});

Comment: If this solution worked for you then accept your answer as a solution to your question